# cannot @Autowired an interface

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'm trying to autowire an interface inside a controller bean

In my context configuration file I've put

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

and

```
<bean id="viewVerbale" class="com.sirfe.controller.VerbaliController" />
```

my controller class is

```
@Controller
public class VerbaliController {


    @Autowired
    VerbaliRepository repository;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VerbaliController.class);


    @RequestMapping(value = "/sirfe/verbale/{sequVerbale:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewVerbale(@PathVariable("sequVerbale") String sequVerbale) {

        logger.debug("welcome() - sequVerbale {}", sequVerbale);

        Verbali verbale = repository.findOne(Long.parseLong(sequVerbale));


        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("sirfe/verbali/viewVerbale");
        model.addObject("sequVerbale", sequVerbale);

        return model;

    }

}
```

my interface signature is

```
public interface VerbaliRepository extends CrudRepository<Verbali, Long>  { }
```

and when I launch my app I get

```
 Could not autowire field: com.sirfe.repository.VerbaliRepository com.sirfe.controller.VerbaliController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.sirfe.repository.VerbaliRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Comment: Where have you registered your repository?

Comment: anywhere, I'm trying to understand where do I have to register it

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to use Spring JPA repository.

In order to have Spring create bean for your repository interfaces, you need in applicationContext.xml to declare what package to scan

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.sirfe.repository" />
```

Doing so, Spring will generate bean implementing the interface for you.

See [Spring JPA Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Comment: I have done as you suggested but I get this error: 'Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#59ab51b0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined'

Comment: You didn't setup your spring project, you need to define multiple bean such as entiyManagerFactory, i suggest you need to read and follow http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring is complaining that it cannot find a valid bean definition that matches, ie there is no bean defined that is an implementation of `VerbaliRepository`.

You need to define a bean or alternatively annotate an implementation class with `@Component` eg

```
<bean id="myRepository" class="com.foo.bar.MyRepository" />
```

or

```
@Component
public class MyRepository implements VerbaliRepository {
 ....
}
```

Comment: I've already tried first solution and I get this error 'Error creating bean with name 'myRepository' defined in ServletContext resource - Specified class is an interface'